# Can opponents differentiate bardic performance from normal music?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

I have this plan where if the PC would come to make a famous local warrior angry he would challenge them to a duel. The duel would happen in the town's square where merchants and local performers surrounds the duel circle. My plan was for the local warrior to have a friend, a bard, passing himself as a local performer and use his bardic performance to give him an edge in battle. Assuming he can hear the song clearly (spectators are expected to keep it down or they can be fined for disturbing a duel), is it fair to assume anyone not targeted by the bardic performance wouldn't notice the difference with normal music? The only way I can think of is an Arcana skill check but in general, is bardic music noticeably different from music for an untrained witness? Any mention of this in 5th edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the bard is written, and what we know about spells in 5e. The answer to this question is either maybe, or probably not.

Reading the Bard's intro/flavor text, it's clear that they are using normal music as an instrument of their power. It's their own innate ability that truly gives the music it's punch.

We also know that spell casting is not apparent unless it's accompanied by identifiable V or S components. We also know that the creature upon whom a spell is cast may will be unawares of said casting (BD&D 80).

Thus, if the bard is playing normal sounding music there is a really good chance it's indistinguishable from other possible music.

However, that's not to say that your PCs are powerless. This is, I think, a great use for skills like arcana, performance, perception and investigation to work in concert to determine that there is a bard in the crowd, identify him among the minstrels and disable him so the bout may continue fairly. In other words, even though it may be indistinguishable from other music, your PCs should be able to detect that *something* is amiss and deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot.

Bardic Inspiration is just that - inspiration. There is no mention in the text of it being magical or arcane. You simply are much better at inspiring others than a layman.

Specifically, the text on **PHB, Page 53, Bardic Inspiration** reads

> You can inspire others through stirring words or music.

In your example, I think it is fair to assume that onlookers would take it as an especially motivating cheer, as that is what it is.